# Bind 2 fields in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind 2 field in aspx page

using this script

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblListText" Text=<%# Eval("CodeType") %> : <%# Eval("Code") %> > </asp:Label>
```

but U i am getting this error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'
```

I tried

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblListText" Text=<%# Eval("CodeType")  : # Eval("Code") %> > </asp:Label>
```

got this

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line
```

tried

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblListText" Text=<%# Eval("CodeType")  :  Eval("Code") %> > </asp:Label>
```

got

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
```

not sure how can I get CodeType then colon then Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblListText" Text='<%#Eval("CodeType").ToString() +" : "+ Eval("Code").ToString() %>' > </asp:Label>
```